# Copy paste from different spreadsheets by user input of sheet name

Tags: google-apps-script

How to get the input from users using prompting, what function should I need to use here?
var ss = sss.getSheetByName(*'bbbbb'*);
'bbbbb' needs to be given by users as per requirement through prompt display.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
const bbbbb = ui.prompt('Enter bbbbb','Enter bbbbbb',ui.ButtonSet.OK).getResponseText();
```

[Class ui](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui.html)